# How to attribute code from a project under Apache V2 in a new project?

Tags: apache-2.0

I have some code I've posted on git hub (https://github.com/blackears/Photoshop-Perspective-Tool) and recently I got an email from someone wanting to know how they might use it in their own project, and in particular they need to attribute license information.

From what they've stated, it sounds like they've broken my original single file into several separate files.  They also mentioned that they'd like to release it under a new license, but they didn't say which one.  They also say they've added some new content in the form of additional UI boxes.

I'm not an expert with licenses.  How does the Apache V2 deal with modifying and releasing code in a new form?  What's the correct way for this new project to attribute my original repository?

Answer (score 3):

> How does the Apache V2 deal with modifying and releasing code in a new form?

It is fine with it.  The [Apache licence](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Apache-2.0) says in s4 that

> *You may reproduce and distribute copies of the
>         Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without
>         modifications*

There are a few conditions to this grant.

> What's the correct way for this new project to attribute my original repository?

Two of those conditions appear in ss 4c and 4d, which say that

> *(c) You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works
>             that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and
>             attribution notices from the Source form of the Work* [...]
>
> *(d) If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
>             distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
>             include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained
>             within such NOTICE file* [...]

So the best way for them to attribute you is to preserve your copyright notices, and for you to add a `NOTICE` file to your source, pointing to your repository, which they will therefore reproduce in any sources they redistribute, possibly adding their own modifications.